# VSCode: see the whole git commit diff

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

There are plenty of questions about how to get the file diff related to a commit, but I can't find anywhere a way to see **the whole commit diff**, just like Atom does:

[image]

I'm really struggling finding a way to do that with VSCode, none of the extensions I've tried so far has this feature.

Comment: go to the SCM bar and select the modified file and a diff window will be opened, open the file and use one of the buttons in the top-right of the window